# Raspberry Pi Xbee serial.Serial timeout not working Python

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, infinite-loop, pyserial

I am trying to connect Rasberry Pi with Xbee on UART header ttyAMA0

Both are connected and I am getting response of +++ -> OK

Xbee is on mode 2 API

```
s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=5)
xb = ZigBee(s)
xb.send('at', command="SH")
print "working till now"
ansh = xb.wait_read_frame()
print "don't wait here there is a time out"
```

I am getting output

> working till now

And code goes for infinite wait

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem with the "SH" at command. After a LOT of debugging and pretty much taking apart the Python-Xbee library I eventually found the solution!
Add "escaped=True" to the constructor:

xb = Zigbee(s, escaped=True)

It would seem that the SH (High Address) response contains bytes which need escaping. Also check your API mode matches.

Comment: After reseting the Xbee it SH works as it should but at every restart it stops working.. Means I need to reset Xbee manually after every restart